# Number of maximal cliques in a ($2C_4$, $C_5$, $P_5$)-free graph

Tags: graphs, reference-request, clique

So far, I have found out that chordal graphs have [linear number of maximal cliques](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/75/531/CS-TR-75-531.pdf) with respect to the number of vertices.
In general case, it is exponential.

I am trying to determine whether the number of maximal cliques in a $(2C_4, C_5,P_5)$-free graph is linear or polynomial with respect to the number of vertices.

In a $(2C_4, C_5,P_5)$-free graph, the largest induced cycle is of length 4, and no two 4-cycles are edge-disjoint.

Is there a paper that mentions such result?

Comment: FWIW, every (connected) $P_5$-free has either a dominating clique or a dominating $P_3$. Also, if it helps, the class of $(C_5,P_5)$-free graphs is also known as the class of *perfect connected-dominant* graphs (i.e., that's the class of graphs for which the domination number equals the connected domination number for every induced subgraph). For a proof of the characterization and more, see Zverovich's 2003 paper "Perfect connected-dominant graphs".

Comment: Also on [math.se]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856299/number-of-maximal-cliques-in-a-2c-4-c-5-p-5-free-graph

Comment: @plshelp you seem to be missing the understanding that being X-free means having not X as an **induced** subgraph.

Comment: I think @Juho 's comments should be enough to solve this. There is a dominating clique (which will be one maximal clique), and a lot of domination properties. For every vertex outside the dominating clique, it forms a maximal clique along with every vertex which dominates it ( since if x dominates y, x's neighbours include all of y's neighbours).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47691/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/117238/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3856299/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answered also on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47691/)

A ($2C_4$, $C_5$, $P_5$)-free graph may have exponentially many maximal cliques.
For example, the complement of the disjoint union of $n/3$ triangles with $3^{n/3}$ maximal cliques is $K_1 \cup K_2$-free, and thus has none of $2C_4$, $C_5$, $P_5$ appear as an induced subgraph.
https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02760024

Note: If the complement of a graph has $k$ pairwise independent edges, then they give you $2^k$ maximal cliques. Conversely, it is known that the number of maximal cliques is upper-bounded by a function of the maximum number of independent edges in the complement .
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/net.3230230308

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer here. This is a very useful answer (including the comment discussions at TCS.SE) for my ongoing study. In case you wonder the reason that I stumbled upon this problem; it is about a combinatorial problem about disk intersection graphs. Please do not hesitate to ask for a detailed explanation in detail.